# Connecting tree nodes in android graphics

Tags: android, html, graphics, opengl-es, android-canvas

How can I create drag and drop graphics in Android almost similar to html5's canvas. Specifically I want to mimic how ancestry.com's android app "family tree" screen is in the picture below. I want to be able to drag/drop the nodes and connect/disconnect them. I also want the screen to seem "endless"; if you've used ancestry.com's android app you will notice that in this screen below you can move the entire tree left/right until no more nodes are left. My guess is that the nodes in these screens are image buttons and they use some type of horizontal scroll view, but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help in advance! :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: How exactly would I implement ViewGroup to achieve my goal? The buttons, images, nodes, connections, etc...?

Comment: I'm currently developing a HTML5 Canvas library to do diagramming exactly like this, but its in private alpha and will be proprietary (ie, cost money). My email is in my profile if you're interested though.

Comment: I would like to develop this basic functionality myself. Nothing too major I just want to be able to have a tree similar to the screen shots. It seems like it would be fairly easy. If you can explain how to do this on a very high level I think I'd have no problem fully implementing it.

Comment: btw I need a high level version of how to do it in Android not html5, I've already created a tree like structure similar to this in html5.